# Replace single field numbers with double field numbers (1->01)

Tags: sort, text-formatting, numeric-data

I have the following file, beginning with

```
male 9
male 11
male 9
male 1
female 4
female 13
male 14
```

If I use

```
sort -u -k1,1 -k2,2n
```

this returns

```
female 13
female 4
male 1
male 11
male 14
male 9
male 9
```

How can I make the single-digit numbers show as 01, 02, etc. so they will sort correctly?

**Update:**

The commenter who told me to just move the `-u` to the back was correct.

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -u
```

worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Do you really just want to sort by the numeric column?

Comment: what version of `sort` do you have? What does `sort --version` show? Because I can't reproduce this with GNU sort, regardless of if I use `-k2,2n`, `-k2n,2`, or `-k2n,2n`, it sorts the numbers in the correct order (i.e. `4` before `13`, and `1`, `9`, `11`, `14`). Of course just `-k2,2` without the `n` would get a lexicographic sort, but you did have the `n` there.

Comment: @ilkkachu it's reproducible if you include the initial `-u`. Put that to the back and all's good. The OP was very close and definitely had tried to find a solution.

Comment: @roaima, I tried it with that exact command! Though only with GNU sort (but two different versions). I don't mean to blame them for _not_ trying to find a solution, the solution they have _works_ (for me). I just wondered if it's an issue with a particular implementation. I thought I saw your answer have `-k2n,2`, so I started wondering if the location of the `n` flag mattered, but that didn't make a difference either. (and now I see `-k2,2n` in your answer too, so maybe I just read that wrong the first time.)

Comment: @ilkkachu and now I can't get the original `sort` to fail either.

Comment: If where you put the `-u` makes a difference then your `sort` is broken. The minimal thing that would explain the output you got would be not having `n` at the end of `-k2,2n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined "*sort correctly*" anywhere, so I'm going to assume that you want to group by the first column and order by ascending numerical value of the second, with duplicate values removed. This solution isn't what you've actually asked for, but it seems to be what you want.

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -u datafile
female 4
female 13
male 1
male 9
male 11
male 14
```

If you really want the second column padded to have two digits you could use this

```
xargs printf "%s %02d\n" <datafile
male 09
male 11
male 09
male 01
female 04
female 13
male 14
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order by the second column only, you can try this (with GNU `sed`):

```
sed -E 's/ ([0-9]{1}$)/ 0\1/' file | sort -u -k2,2n
```

Output:

```
male 01
female 04
male 09
male 11
female 13
male 14
```

Comment: @roaima, true, edited.